# SSIS - Calculate an interval of dates with datetime fields

Tags: datetime, ssis, date-difference

Let's assume that I have some dates like these:

```
2014-01-23 14:52  (today)
2014-01-22-15:35
2014-01-21 10:35
2014-01-20 09:45
2014-01-19 17:58
2014-01-18 14:05
2014-01-17 13:22
```

Now I need to take into account only the 5 previous days to the current day, so for me  they will be:

```
2014-01-22-15:35
2014-01-21 10:35
2014-01-20 09:45
2014-01-19 17:58
2014-01-18 14:05
```

In SSIS I wrote the next instruction in a conditional split task:

```
date > DATEADD("DD",-5,GETDATE()) && date < DATEADD("DD",-1,GETDATE())
```

But the result that I am having depends of the HOUR in which I execute the work flow.

So, for instance, if I execute it TODAY (2014-01-23) at 13:42. I am not going to seeing 2014-01-22-15:35 because it is after a complete day consider the hour (13:42)
and what I need is to see all the data that have a date at any moment from yesterday.

My question is, how can I indicate that I need ALL the dates of the previous days from today at 00:00?. In other words, how can I compute this interval for ALL the hours of the previous 5 days without taking into consideration the hour of execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are doing this in SQL you can try to cast the dateTime to a date

```
Declare @today date = getdate()
Declare @now datetime = getdate()
Cast(@now as date) between dateadd("DD",-5,@today) AND dateadd("DD",-1,@today)
```

let me know if that helps?

Comment: thanks a lot for your replay. I used it to solve the problem in SSIS and in works perfectly.